# programmatically access google search watchlist

Tags: api, video, google-api, google-search

Google offers you the possibility with Google search to track, like and rate movies or TV shows. You can see those options blended with the information of a given movie when searching for it. You then can have access to that data later by searching `my watchlist`.

I've been trying without success to know if I can access programmatically (e.g. is there an API) to that data (movies inside of my watchlist, ratings...). Is it possible?

Many thanks,
Joel

Comment: just for reference, you can access the list [here](https://www.google.com/save). So maybe a web crawler like [Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can help?

Comment: same question has been asked [here](https://support.google.com/googletv/thread/113392077/does-anyone-know-a-way-to-view-google-tv-watchlist-on-the-web-or-maybe-with-developer-api-command?hl=en) in google forum