# Google API to extract all my saved list in realtime

Tags: google-api

Is there a Google API to extract all my saved lists from this page [here](https://www.google.com/saved)?

I tried looking into the list of available API's in the [Google API EXplorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer), but I don't think its available.

I'm looking for a way to make use of my various saved lists in a note taking platform to add notes or plan my travel/food travel plans. So whenever I find a new place to travel or new restaurant to try out, I'd like to save it in google and use that to extract it in my notes
& calendar and plan for it.

---

- I know that we can extract all my data using [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/), but this is not real-time.
- I found similar questions/posts listed below, but almost all of them say that its not possible or have a unstable workaround

  - [API for bookmarks/saved places](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68749469)
  - [programmatically access google search watchlist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64060991/6908282)
  - [Obtain list of My Places from Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50964713/6908282)
  - [Is there an API call to get a list of saved places in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32516268/6908282)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no api for that currently.

Comment: Do you know if there is a plan to provide an API or anything that can give realtime data?

Comment: I cant answer for google but its been years I wouldn't hold your breath